# How to do new Line in C# Webservice

Tags: c#, email, asmx

I am trying to make new Lines using a Web service (SOAP in asmx) Rather than have it send the Email with new Lines using "\n", it just shows a straight Line.

My code looks like this  :

```
[WebMethod]
public bool SendCashBagSerial(string email, string fullname, string SerialNumCode, string purpleworksemail) 
{
    string to = email; //To address    
    string from = purpleworksemail;
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);

    string EmailBody = "Dear "+ fullname +"\n Your CashBag Serial is : "+ SerialNumCode + "\n Please Quote this Number to Complete your Request. \n Regards, \n Purpleworks \n ";
    message.Subject = "Your Cash Bag Serial!";
    message.Body = EmailBody;
    message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
    message.IsBodyHtml = true;
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.office365.com", 587);
    System.Net.NetworkCredential basicCredential1 = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("*******@*************", "*******");
    client.EnableSsl = true;
    client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Credentials = basicCredential1;
    try
    {
        client.Send(message);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Is there something I am not doing correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line breaks are often 2 characters, a line feed and a carriage return. To replicate this you do `\r\n`... but your email is html

```
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
```

So you need to use `<br>`

Comment: Did so, returned it as a one Liner